# Jenkins specific task to run on master

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-cli

Lets say, I have a button that does specific task. I want that task to be run on masters only. How do I do that.
I don't want to restrict the job build.

Comment: What's wrong with setting "Restrict where this project can be run" to master ?

Comment: That will restrict the build as well. I don't want to restrict the build.